# For loop for differences column n + 1 and column n

Tags: loops, for-loop, sum, col

I would like to create a for loop that:
- calculates the sum of each of the column
- subtract the values of column x from column x+1

I have never made a for loop before, so I am getting a bit stuck here. [Example of the columns with the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAyI6.png)

Anybody that could help me out?

Comment: Hey @Wouter welcome to stack overflow. From your question it looks like you are new to programming so I think it would be better for you that you first try the problem yourself and if that does not work out post that solution here so we can help you out. Good luck

Comment: Which language do you want to use?  Are your data values coming from a text file?

Comment: I use R, and my data values come from a .csv file

Comment: I'd suggest starting with this:  https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/for-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some starter code, in case you choose to use C.

```
int columnSum( int colNum )
{
    int theSum = 0;
    //  TBD
    return theSum;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int firstCol = 0;
    int lastCol = 4;
    for ( int col = firstCol; col <= lastCol; col++ )
    {
        int sum = columnSum( col );
    }
    //  You probably want to save those sums above into an array.
    //  Here, you could do your subtractions with your saved sums.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1/22/2020 1/23/2020 1/24/2020 1/25/2020 1/26/2020 1/27/2020 1/28/2020 1/29/2020 1/30/2020 
  555       653       941      1434      2118      2927      5578      6166      8234
```

So basically I want to subtract 653 - 555, 941 - 653 etc., but not manually.

Comment: What you have posted here would be better as an edit to your original post, instead of as an answer.  It's a clarification, but not really an answer.